# Using jquery to scroll a picture by following the mouse

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hard to explain this by a short title. I would like to recreate something that is made in flash, but with using either a jquery plugin or css\html.

[Link to current flash](http://inord.no/?calcId=mobil)
If you press "Altaposten.no mobil" on the left side, you will be able to hover over the iphone.

Any tips?

Comment: [`mousemove`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mousemove) will be your friend here

Comment: http://valums.com/scroll-menu-jquery/ might help you here.

Comment: To elaborate on @Mooseman, the part that's important for recreating what they're doing in flash is the calculation. 
`var left = (e.pageX - div.offset().left) * (ulWidth-divWidth) / divWidth;`
For you it would the height (Y values)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

I ended up using this plugin to recreate this problem.

Its very nice.

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller/